# Consulta MYSQL donde muesta resistros de una tabla, si hay coincidencia con otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo 2 tablas en una base: `tabla1` y `tabla2`. Cuyas columnas las llamo dato1, dato2, etc...

La `tabla1` tiene datos de personas:

```
dato1 = id, 
dato2 = nombre, 
dato3 = apellido, 
dato4 = edad, 
dato5 = teléfono, 
dato6 = compañía de celular.
```

La `tabla2` tiene los números de teléfono:

```
dato1 = id, 
dato2 = número de teléfono.
```

Necesito ver los datos de la `tabla1`, siempre y cuando ciertas condiciones de la `tabla1` estén presentes y el número de teléfono exista en la `tabla2`.

Yo intenté con el siguiente query, pero me da error:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla1
WHERE dato2=Pedro and dato4=45 and dato5=44789858 
IF EXISTS (SELECT dato1 FROM tabla2 WHERE 
tabla2.dato2 = tabla1.dato5);
```

¿Alguna sugerencia de como puedo lograrlo? no tengo muchos conocimientos en `MYSQL`.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Muestra los errores que tiro tu query.. supongo que si dato2 es un varchar, entonces deberia ir entre comillas simples.

Comment: Y creo que estan mal armadas tus tablas.. que es dato5?? (y por favor, usa los nombres de campos que corresponde!!!! dato5 no es un nombre de campo valido.. porque no se llama telefono???) Digo, que contiene dato5?

Comment: Prueba a usar esta [herramienta](http://sqlfiddle.com/) para explicar mejor tus dudas

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, dato5 es el campo de los números de teléfono.

Comment: Lee los links que te pase... Contesta todas las preguntas que te hacemos... si dato5 es el numero de telefono, que hay en la otra tabla?

Comment: @gbianchi la tabla2 tiene: dato1=id, dato2=número de teléfono, dato3=compañía telefónica.

Comment: Esa tabla esta mal... la tabla 2 no deberia tener esos campos. Deberia tener el id del campo de la tabla1. Si no, que vas a guardar en dato5 cuando no tenga telefono? null? entonces para que existe la tabla2? es mas, con lo que vos planteas, la tabla2 no tiene sentido pq es una relacion 1 a 1. Te recomendaria que leas sobre normalizacion de tablas. Tu problema no es el query, son tus tablas.

Comment: @gbianchi muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Voy a leer sobre normalización de tablas. Igual la solución que me pasaste funciona perfecto.

Comment: Yo no pase ninguna solucion @Carlos. Y tus tablas estan mal y te van a llevar a errores peores.

Comment: @gbianchi perdón, pensé que tú habías subido la solución.

Comment: @Carlos no leiste ni uno de los enlaces que te pase, lo que es **realmente** importante.

Comment: @gbianchi Respecto a las tablas, tabla2 no tiene nada que ver con tabla1... tabla2 tiene muchos otros datos referidos a compañías telefónicas. Y con esta búsqueda, solamente muestro los datos de las personas de tabla1 cuyo número de teléfono pertenece a una de las compañías telefónicas existentes en tabla2. Igualmente voy a leer sobre lo que me recomiendas así aprendo. Gracias!

Comment: Entonces. la tabla2 no tiene un numero de telefono, es solo la compañia? es algo muy distinto a lo que escribiste aca...

Comment: tabla2 tiene una larga lista de números de teléfonos de algunas compañías telefónicas. No todas!!! si la persona seleccionada en tabla1 tiene un número que está dentro de la lista de tabla2, ahí me muestra los datos. No sé si lo explico bien... estoy leyendo los links que me enviaste y aprendiendo un poco más... es mi primer pregunta en este sitio.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No entiendo que hay en tabla2 si el número de teléfono ya existe en dato5 de tabla1. Te recomendaría replantearte la estructura de la base de datos.

Aún así con esta query podrías obtener lo que quieres

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabla1
WHERE dato2='Pedro' and dato4=45 and dato5=44789858 
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM tabla2 
  WHERE tabla1.dato5 = tabla2.dato2 
)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto me sirvió. Es justo lo que estaba necesitando!!!